# Unicode error cant decode bytes in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am just starting to make a selenium scriupt and its already returning an error:

````
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape```
````

heres literally my code:

```
import requests, sys, json, csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\serpent\Desktop\code\linked\chromedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following. With a r in front of the string or changing \ to /.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\serpent\Desktop\code\linked\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: so no quotations

Comment: what do u mean? chrome() no quotes in there or at the end?

Comment: oh no LOL those ''' were for stack overflow its not in my code and its still broken

Comment: Ok now try this.